# Modified Poisson regression test for diagnostics and assumptions

Tags: plot, modeling, poisson, diagnostics

Can you please help me with codes in R used to plot the diagnostics and tests for the assumptions of modified Poisson regression (robust Poisson)?
I am not sure which assumptions should I check or how to check for them.
Thank you in advance!